Additional Meanings for John the Baptist, “Prepare the way”
I was pondering on John’s prophecy about preparing the way for Christ. Is there any evidence to support the claim that he also prepared the way for Jesus to feel what it felt like to lose someone close by execution in becoming like us and also John’s death being a foreshadowing of the death of Christ?

John 1:23 - John replied in the words of Isaiah the prophet: “I am a
voice of one calling in the wilderness, ‘Make straight the way for the
Lord.’ ”


This is actually interesting as different evangelists record different quotes:

Matthew 3:1-3 - In those days John the Baptist came, preaching in the wilderness of Judea and saying, “Repent, for the kingdom of
heaven is near.” This is he who was spoken of through the prophet
Isaiah:
“A voice of one calling in the wilderness, ‘Prepare the way for the
Lord, make straight paths for Him.’ ”


Mark 1:2, 3 - As it is written in Isaiah the prophet:
“Behold, I will send My messenger ahead of You, who will prepare Your
way.” (quoting Mal 3)
“A voice of one calling in the wilderness, ‘Prepare the way for the
Lord, make straight paths for Him.’ ” (Quoting Isa 40)


Luke 3:3-6 - as it is written in the book of the words of Isaiah the prophet:
“A voice of one calling in the wilderness, ‘Prepare the way for the
Lord, make straight paths for Him. Every valley shall be filled in,
and every mountain and hill made low. The crooked ways shall be made
straight, and the rough ways smooth. And all humanity will see God’s
salvation.’ ”


John 1:23 - John replied in the words of Isaiah the prophet:
“I am a voice of one calling in the wilderness, ‘Make straight the way
for the Lord.’ ”

First, notice that John does not record anything about the Baptist "preparing the way" - that is recorded by the other three evangelists.  They quote both Mal 3:1 and Isa 40:3, but John does not quote the part about "preparing the way".
Now to the OP's question which is about what is NOT written - we do not know all of the reasons for what is recorded in the Bible.  In this case, all we are told is that John "prepared the way" and "made straight the paths" for Messiah.
However, it is also true that Jesus is recorded as experiencing many things on our behalf (Heb 4:14-16) and the execution of Jesus' cousin is just one.  Thus, we may be confident that whatever trials we experience, Jesus also experienced as well - He overcame without sin.

A stylistic feature of the gospels, which they have in common, is that they describe Jesus' actions and teachings more than his internal feelings.
His feelings are described at important moments. The death of Lazarus: John 11:35 "Jesus wept" ; Healing a man on the Sabbath - Mark 3:5, Jesus looks around at the Pharisees with anger and grief at their hardness of heart ; the Garden of Gethsemane ; overturning the tables ; eloi eloi lama sabachthani. In each of these examples we are not shown much but that makes it more effective.
The gospels' treatments of John the Baptist are quite distinct, but to answer this question for each it's a case of looking at a few descriptions of him (e.g. in Matthew the baptism at 3:1-12 the questioning at 11:1-19, and the beheading at 14:1-12) and deciding if the structure and the use of language point to an emotional lesson, or foreshadow Jesus' crucifixion, or serve other points such as confirming the earlier prophecies.
There is a 'reaction shot' at Matthew 14:13 - one of the rare descriptions of Jesus' emotions is reserved for the news of John the Baptist's death.
But there isn't anything in the text of Matthew to suggest Jesus' divinity makes experiencing human loss difficult for him. It's not the elf-king's daughter coming to find out what mortal life is like - or a 'town mouse and country mouse' setup, with a Perry Index of 352 etc.
At Matthew 14:13 I submit there can be found two things:
(1) Jesus placing his sorrow second to the compassion he feels for the crowds who still come to him for healing.
(2) Jesus wrestling with the mission of salvation, which gradually and eventually becomes sacrificial. He withdraws because John's execution places his ministry in jeopardy. Or perhaps he has omniscient foresight but on first hearing the evangelion we don't know that. His actions are natural for someone who is worried their life or their mission may be cut short.
If Matthew's description accentuates the tension or potential tension between Jesus' divine and human natures, that makes the writing more powerful but probably also contributes to the theological awareness that both are present. Writing a Herculean demigod who doesn't possess any fear of Herod, or a mortal hero asking his divine parent for help - would have been far simpler.
In case it's contended that Matthew predates the Arian controversy, yes he does but it was of a very old type and it's perfectly conceivable he needed to counter the ancient and cross-cultural prohibitions on deifying a human. This isn't long after the posthumous deification of Julius Caesar.
In that sort of context Matthew's description begins to appear extremely tight: it lets us infer that Jesus prayed so we are assured he is fully-human, but it doesn't let us infer that he was cowardly such that we might insult one who is fully-god.
Yes there is certainly foreshadowing. There is a tragic irony in how the way he prepares ends up being fatal. There is the establishment of the antagonists' murderous decadence, and their worldly power. But in Matthew the additional meaning I submit is this Christological one.
